# Flutter App is not running in Android emulator in Windows

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to run my flutter application first time in Android emulator. Unfortunately, I'm facing this issue.

**Flutter log**

```
Flutter crash report.
Please report a bug at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.

## command

flutter run -d emulator-5554 -v

## exception

ArgumentError: Invalid argument(s): Cannot find executable for C:\Users\user\Desktop\NewFlutterApp\android\gradlew.bat.


#0      _getExecutable (package:process/src/interface/local_process_manager.dart:127:5)
#1      LocalProcessManager.start (package:process/src/interface/local_process_manager.dart:43:30)
#2      _DefaultProcessUtils.start (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:462:28)
#3      _DefaultProcessUtils.stream (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:480:35)
#4      buildGradleApp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:388:35)
#5      _AndroidBuilderImpl.buildApk (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_builder.dart:103:13)
#6      AndroidDevice.startApp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart:540:28)
#7      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
#8      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
#9      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
#10     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
#11     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
#12     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
#13     Future._asyncCompleteWithValue.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:567:7)
#14     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
#15     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
#16     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
#17     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
#18     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#19     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#20     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
#21     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)


** ## flutter doctor **


[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.19.0-4.3.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.19.0-4.3.pre at C:\Users\user\Documents\flutter
    • Framework revision 8fe7655ed2 (12 days ago), 2020-07-01 14:31:18 -0700
    • Engine revision 9a28c3bcf4
    • Dart version 2.9.0 (build 2.9.0-14.1.beta)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.1
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Users\user\Desktop\AndroidStudio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Users\user\Desktop\AndroidStudio
    • Flutter plugin version 47.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.46.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.12.2

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • AOSP on IA Emulator • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)
    • Web Server          • web-server    • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
    • Chrome              • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 83.0.4103.116

• No issues found!
```

I couldn't see any issue still in flutter doctor, I require help from Flutter community. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `gradle.bat` in `C:\Users\user\Desktop\NewFlutterApp\android\`? It seems to be missing.

Try `flutter create .` in the root dir.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Gradle.bat is missing, when I try to execute "flutter create ." in root dir, it's not creating gradle.bat.

Answer (score 0):

Actual solution for this issue:

1. Antivirus blocking the sdkmanager.bat file - Add an exception in Antivirus settings
2. Run `flutter create .` to install gradle.bat inside the android.